# python, tornado, apache thrift and cassanda on system for tracking metrics devices

Tags: python, authentication, cassandra, tornado, thrift

I want to create a system for tracking metrics devices.

The main idea is this:

I have same devices connected to internet while they are running to send metrics as velocity, temperature, energy consumption, etc to my web services using HTTP.

To build this solution I'm using the following technologies:

- Python
- Apache Thrift  ---- this allow good performance and description api is more natural
- Tornado Web Server --- Integration with Thrift make public web service of collector data devices.
- Cassandra

Well, I'm a newbie using cassandra but I read many in this days and I did one candidate model for resolve this problem and I want to know if is correct and I know if exist in python using Apache Thrift any library for build  token-based authentication system because I need controlling who is register data in my service if is autorizated.

I think divide in two parts once part for login and other for tracking metrics devices.

```
CREATE KEYSPACE authcollector;

CREATE TABLE authcollector.login (
  username text,
  password text,
  **keyspace_for_metrics** text,
  PRIMARY KEY (username)
);
```

Example:

```
INSERT INTO login (username, password, keyspace_for_metrics) VALUES
('company1_user', 'company1_pass', '***company1_keyspace***')
```

The main idea es with cassandra keyspace is register  all credentials of person or company that used this service. They need register and when they need register data first login in my service with your credential and my service return a authentication token and later using method for register data.

The field **keyspace_for_metrics** contains a hash value that it is the name for keyspace in cassandra for this person or company where insert your data for your devices.

Followed is my template keyspace for collector data.

```
CREATE KEYSPACE collector_{dynamic based in field value of **keyspace_for_metrics**};

CREATE TABLE tracking (
  devices_id text,
  timelog datetime,
  metrics map<text, int>,
  PRIMARY KEY (devices_id, timelog)
);
```

Example:

```
INSERT INTO collector_***company1_keyspace***.tracking (device_id, timelog, metrics) VALUES
('motor-checko', '2014-10-15 12:12:12', {'velocity':100, 'temperature':9, 'energy_consumption':20})
```

I need know if my Cassandra model is correct and I need a python library or example for to implement  token-based authentication  with Apache Thrift.

Comment: Thank you for your corrections. I deleted this part "I'm build a core that permit make it.". Well, I need a example or libraries for implement token-based authentication. Sorry by my syntax english, I hope that you understand me. My native language not is english.